# Loops through values searching a range of data, cuts the row of found value to another sheet

Tags: vba

```
Option Explicit

Sub MLB_Build_Lineups_PhaseI_Test()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim C As Range
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim wsLineups As Worksheet
    Dim c2 As Range
    Dim f As Range
    Dim Check As Range
    Dim CheckCell As Integer
    Dim rngTeam As Range
    Dim rngrwTeam As Range
    Dim rnglineups As Range
    Dim LastTeamName As Long
    Dim wsbuild As Worksheet
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim r As Variant
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim b As Variant
    Dim y As Variant
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set wsLineups = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lineups")
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Set wsbuild = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Build")
    Set rnglineups = wsData.Range("A1:J1501")
    Lastrow = wsData.Range("K" & wsData.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For y = 2 To Lastrow
        
        dict.RemoveAll
    
        For Each C In wsData.Range("Q2", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp))
            v = C.Value
            x = C.Row
            r = C.Column
            Set rngTeam = wsData.Range("K" & y)
            If dict.exists(CStr(v)) Then
                C.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Else
                Set f = wsbuild.Range("C2:J1501").Find(v, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByRows)
                If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    a = f.Row
                    b = f.Column
                    Set rngrwTeam = f.EntireRow.Columns("AF")
                    If rngTeam = rngrwTeam Then
                        Set rw = f.EntireRow.Columns("A").Resize(1, 10)
                        For Each c2 In rw.Cells
                            dict(CStr(c2)) = True
                        Next c2
                        Set rw = f.EntireRow.Columns("A").Resize(1, 36)
                        rw.Cut Destination:=wsLineups.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                        C.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    Else
Retry:
                        a = f.Row + 1
                        Set f = wsbuild.Range("C" & a & ":J1501").Find(v, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByRows)
                        If Not f Is Nothing Then
                            a = f.Row
                            b = f.Column
                            Set rngrwTeam = f.EntireRow.Columns("AF")
                            If rngTeam = rngrwTeam Then
                                Set rw = f.EntireRow.Columns("A").Resize(1, 10)
                                For Each c2 In rw.Cells
                                    dict(CStr(c2)) = True
                                Next c2
                                Set rw = f.EntireRow.Columns("A").Resize(1, 36)
                                rw.Cut Destination:=wsLineups.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                                C.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                            Else
                                If a = 1501 Then
                                    GoTo startover
                                End If
                                GoTo Retry
startover:
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    C.Interior.Color = vbRed
                End If
            End If
        Next C
        wsData.Range("Q:Q").Interior.Color = xlNone
    Next y
    
    Set wsData = Sheets("Data")
    wsData.Range("U:V").Interior.Color = xlNone
    
    'Set Check = wsLineups.Range("A" & HowManyLineups + 1)
    'If IsEmpty(Check) = True Then
    'Call test
    'End If

End Sub
```

The code above works but it takes way too long and is not sustainable for the short time frame that I have to run it. I am looking for some recommendations on how to drastically speed it up. It is a very easy process but I am still learning VBA and looking for some help.

I attached two images to help with the code above and the following description. The code searches for values on wsdata column "Q" in the range on wsbuild columns A2:J1501. If it finds the value it compares the value on wsdata column "K" to the value of the found value row on wsbuild column "AF" if it matches then it cuts it if it doesn't then it find the next value in the range. Like I said before it works just takes forever. Thanks.